# Is cuda::SURF_cuda faster than cv::xfeatures2d::SURF?

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, computer-vision, surf

I'm trying to build opencv with CUDA support to compare `cuda::SURF_CUDA`  with `cv::xfeatures2d::SURF`, [but it's challenging](http://answers.opencv.org/question/128213/cmake-on-opencv-with-cuda-compiles-from-scratch-everytime/).

However, suppose that I want to get SURF descriptors for an high performance, real time application. Yeah yeah, I know that FAST, or ORB are more suitable descriptors, but they're binaries and I need euclidean descriptors.

Anyway, the point is that I want to know which of these two implementations is faster **given only one (query) image**.  I think it's important because someone told me that CUDA is reasonable to use only when a lot of images has to be processed, since the time to load them in the GPU memory becomes small compared to the time for computing descriptors, but I don't know if this is true.

Another reason because I post this is that I have only one NVIDIA GT755m, which is not an high-level GPU, and so my results could be not so good for this reason. On the other hand, I'm trying to improve the parallel section of `cv::xfeatures2d::SURF` (and test it on a Xeon Phi with 64 cores).

Comment: It is and of course you are always dependent of the hardware. Have you tried to look for the specs of your gt 755m and compare it with you CPU? It should give you a hint. But anyway, I do not believe that the CPU version will benefit of the 64 cores that you have.

Comment: @NAmorim thanks for your comment. I'm not a CUDA expert (actually I almost know nothing about it) but when we talk about GPU applications, shouldn't we consider an overhead (that we can't rid off) to load our data (the image query) in the GPU memory (or something like that)? Then when we talk about loading/saving stuff to/from one memory to the other (especially from/to HD) this is going to be very expensive. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not the best person to be discussing this since I'm not an expert too. But you are right, there is indeed an overhead to transfer data from one place to another. But from my experience of playing with CPU/GPU parallelism, on CPU you have a lower overhead but also a soft parallelism (imagine 4 cores at max) and on GPU an higher overhead but aggressive parallelism (300+ cores in your case I believe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "the time to load them in the GPU memory becomes small compared to the time for computing descriptors" - OP

Yes you are correct. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41098416/4534261) and [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/999803/cuda-programming-and-performance/why-warm-up-/post/5109038/#5109038) for explanations on why CUDA kernels seem to be slow on their 1st runs.

For your application, it will depend entirely on the CPU and GPU you're running the code on and how well the CPU and GPU code is written. Like @NAmorim said, it will be dependent on how much overhead your code creates and how much parallelism it is able to utilize.

Note that it could also depend on how many features you are processing as this factors into both CPU/GPU computation time along with a large portion of GPU overhead (think uploading/downloading the descriptors to the GPU).