# CUDA kernel runs faster the second time it is run - why?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda, gpgpu

I am programming my first real application in CUDA, and I have come to the point where I need to know how long executions of kernels take. However, as said in the title, I do not understand why, in applications that run a kernel more than once, the time taken for the *second* launch of the kernel is much much shorter than the time taken for the first.

For example, in the code below:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

void runCuda(unsigned int size);

__global__ void addKernel(const int arraySize)
{
    1 + 1;
}

void doStuff(int arraySize)
{
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    addKernel <<<(arraySize + 31) / 32, 32 >>> (arraySize);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << "Duration: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << '\n';
    cudaDeviceReset();
}

int main()
{
    doStuff(1e6);
    doStuff(1e6);

    return 0;
}
```

the kernel only does some basic addition, and it is called one million times. The output of the program above is usually something like:

```
Duration: 1072
Duration: 97
```

the two numbers change, but remain consistently around 1000 and 100. The fact that the same kernel runs so much faster the second time makes no sense to me.

Comment: This is lazy context initialization on the first call. See the licked duplicate

Comment: @talonmies Thank you. However, let me just say I disagree with marking this duplicate. *My* question is asking "why does X happen?", while the linked question is asking "X happens because of Y, can you please tell me how to avoid Y?". To me, these are two different question. Just like me, another user with the same problem might not even know they are actually looking for the question you linked...

Comment: You can follow the instructions in my answer. The kennel is the first apii call in your code. Add an initializing call before you start calling kennels and the performance difference will vanish. You can't avoid it, the runtime had fixed overhead costs. It is only a question of what captures the time

Comment: @talonmies I tried doing just that, and it has the effect I need. Thank you. Also, link to that question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166799/any-particular-function-to-initialize-gpu-other-than-the-first-cudamalloc-call for anyone that encounters this thread.

Comment: Do in other words, the answer I closed this as a duplicate was the answer you wanted and blue we have an unanswered dangling question thanks to whomever incorrectly reopened this. Well done......

Comment: @talonmies Like I said above, no, the answer to the question was not the answer of the "duplicated question". The answer to the linked question is "use `cudaFree(0)` before your first kernel launch". The answer to *my* question is "This happens because you did not initialize GPU yet". These two answers, while similar, are not the same. And if opened questions bother you that much, feel free to add a short answer and I will accept it. Or I can do it myself, which I plan to if no other answers appear. Or vote to close, in which case I guess we agree to disagree.

Comment: This is why you need to call a warm up kernel before timing. I agree with @talonmies that this question is a dup.

Comment: @Oblivion Like I explained, I disagree about the dup. The question you say I am duplicating already assumes we *know* we need to "warm up" the kernel. "You need to warm up the kernel" is an *answer* to my question, and only after having this question, the other question can even be asked. The two questions are related in a similar way as the questions "Which male tennis player won the most GS titles" and "How many GS titles does Roger Federer have" are related. Related and duplicated are not the same thing.

Comment: @5xum The problem is nobody posted a relevant answer and as a reader I won't find this question useful in future. You may edit the "relevant" question to your question or answer yourself. The point is we all want a reliable source

Comment: @Oblivion My plan is to add an answer to this question once I have the time to write it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's overhead when a program launches the first Cuda kernel.
you should first launch a blank kernel when you check the running time of your kernels

Comment: Sorry to turn up late to the party, but can you add an example of a 'blank kernel' that'll do the trick?  I find that mine has no observable effect. `void kernel_warm_up( int* dummy ) { *dummy = 1; }` ... `kernel_warm_up <<<1, 1 >>>( /*cuda ptr to int*/ );`

Comment: I still think it would be useful to provide an example, but it turned out my issue was to do with not pre-fetching memory, rather than a cold start.

Comment: @EddInglis 'blank kernel' is also called warmup kernel(in most case).
You can google it or see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098237/is-the-warmup-code-necessary-when-measuring-cuda-kernel-running-time)

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your GPU/CPU is increasing its clock speed because it has work to do. OS scheduling might also interfere, but that's not the main thing you're experiencing here.

Timing code execution time like this usually means at least averaging over multiple runs, and if you want to do better, excluding outliers.

I'm sure that if you add a few more `doStuff(1e6);` lines, they will lie closer to the second result than the first.

Comment: Indeed they do, all results after the first are consistently around 100 milliseconds. I had my suspicions that your answer is probably what causes the discrepancy, but on the other hand, I was/am afraid that some very low level optimization would be to blame, in which case the second result would actually be less informative. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: There are also various other causes, ranging from driver kernel caching, device memory caching, etc. all of which I know nothing useful except that they might exist. If you remove the CUDA from your question, you'll notice the exact same thing happening with plain C++ (if you manage to trick the optimizer into not optimizing everything away), so this is at least a baseline feature you need to take into account.

Comment: All of this has absolutely nothing to do with the problem

Comment: @talonmies wrt reopening: see [the OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57709333/cuda-kernel-runs-faster-the-second-time-it-is-run-why/57709436?noredirect=1#comment101863549_57709333). With respect to your "nothing to with the problem" comment, a simple CUDA-less demonstration: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73f34a927b2687ad. Note I am not claiming my answer contains the full answer, but it surely is a component of the delay.

Comment: This has nothing to do with OP's observation.

Answer (score 0):

You will find that on your first run almost all of the extra time is spent on your first cudaMalloc(). This is a initialization where it is determining device and swap and memory conditions that can only partly be mitigated.

Answer (score 0):

The better timing method for kernels can be found in "CUDA C++ best Practices Guide", like the following code:

```
cudaEvent_t start, stop;
float time;
cudaEventCreate(&start);
cudaEventCreate(&stop);
cudaEventRecord( start, 0 );
kernel<<<grid,threads>>> ( d_odata, d_idata, size_x, size_y,
 NUM_REPS);
cudaEventRecord( stop, 0 );
cudaEventSynchronize( stop );
cudaEventElapsedTime( &time, start, stop );
cudaEventDestroy( start );
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't worked in this setup, but most likely in the first run the kernel needs to compile. Shaders for GPU must be compiled in runtime since each devise compiles it a bit differently. Otherwise, you'd have to make as many executables as there are devises, plus different variation for each OS and whatever else contributes to the code compilation (driver version).

Comment: There's no way to tell whether the kernel needs to compile, because OP hasn't provided compilation information or any information about the GPU they are running on.  But it's certainly possible to avoid kernel compilation at runtime, and even in that scenario, OP's observation would still persist, for the reasons alluded to in comments to the question.