# Best way to "warm up" the GPU with CUDA?

Tags: cuda, gpu

I'm aware of the thread [Is the warmup code necessary when measuring CUDA kernel running time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098237/is-the-warmup-code-necessary-when-measuring-cuda-kernel-running-time)

But even with the great internet, this CUDA book and the code samples that go with it available, I can't find an example of a warmup kernel.

My question is: What is the best, cleanest way to "warm up" the GPU with CUDA before running experiments with timers?

Comment: That's only necessary when you're profiling. Even then, its usefulness is questionable. What's your goal?

Comment: @3Dave At this point, as a beginner, my goal is first of all to gain knowledge in case I need it

Comment: (Not trying to be a smartass, the real answer is I am using CUDA for research in my master thesis, and im just trying to soak up knowledge)

Comment: Been there, done that. My thesis was on GPGPU implementation of FDTD. Warmup isn't necessary. Getting all of your data onto the GPU takes time, but that should be a separate category in your performance analysis, labeled "Overhead BS"

Comment: A `cudaFree(0)` at the beginning doesn't hurt. That ensures that lazy context creation is already out of the way.

Comment: Well, sometimes the best thing to do is run it twice and measure the second time only. But yeah, this is only for performance figures. Do not warmup your day-to-day- use.

Answer (score 2):

In the examples of the book ["Professional CUDA C Programming"](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Professional+CUDA+C+Programming-p-9781118739310) a simple kernel similar to this was defined to be executed on each visible GPU as a warmup:

```
__global__ void warm_up_gpu(){
  unsigned int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  float ia, ib;
  ia = ib = 0.0f;
  ib += ia + tid; 
}
```